# Is there a better way to create a Multi Index with columns preceding the multi-index data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3482.png) is my current output and what I'd like to improve.

Here is the code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(8, 3),
                  index=[['Fund Name', 'Jerry Partners','', '', 'Fund Name','Boris LTD','',''],
                         ['$Bln AUM','2Bln','', '', '$Bln AUM','6Bln','',''],
                         ['Count', '21', ' ', ' ','Count','11', ' ', ' '], 
                        ['ticker1', 'ticker2', 'ticker3', 'ticker4', 'ticker1', 'ticker2', 'ticker3', 'ticker4']], 
                        columns=['%Own','Purchase Price','Tot Value'])
df
```

Is there any other way to place regular columns before the multi-index?
I'd rather not repeat "Fund Name", "$Bln AUM", etc. as well as complicate my DataFrame construction.

\\\EDIT:

Here is some more information on the data that I'm wrangling. I hope this is sufficient. I have a collection of 71 funds and the tickers of their respective 10 largest investments.

Some of these funds have less than 10 investments, which is where I believe things get complicated.

I also have the assets under management of the fund, and for each ticker I have the amount owned, and the price at which the stock was purchased.
Given this information, I have a dictionary where Keys are Fund Names and Values are a List of the Tickers, like so:

`{'AKO Capital': [array(['LIN', 'BKNG', 'EBAY', 'V', 'EL', 'GOOG', 'NKE', 'RACE', 'OTIS','PG'], dtype=object)], 'Ackman Trust': [array(['BRK.B', 'WM', 'CAT', 'CNI', 'WMT', 'ECL', 'CCI', 'FDX', 'UPS','SDGR'], dtype=object)]}`
And so forth. The % owned and price at purchase are in separate arrays. What I would like to create here is the following multi index (dots denote in-between rows):

```
Manager    |Ticker |% Owned
AKO Capital|LIN    |25%
           |BKNG   |11%
           |EBAY   |13%
            ...........
           |OTIS   |5%
           |PG     |3.5%
AckmanTrust|BRK.B  |5%
           |WM     |15%
           |CAT    |12%
            ............
           |UPS    |5%
           |SGDR   |7%
```

I would be happy to just have the Manager/Ticker levels working and figure out the rest myself.

Thank you.

Comment: Oh you should definitely repeat the actual values as opposed to filling them with `'',` because with your current method pandas has absolutely no idea the `''` under `'Jerry Partners'` should be grouped with it. I can guarantee this will lead to countless mistakes and complications for what would normally be trivial manipulations.

Comment: And by repeat I mean however you're getting the data, you should also be storing that information along with it, that way you can create those columns and then a simple `.set_index(['col1', 'col2', ...])` gives you the MultiIndex

Comment: Could you provide the table your data comes from?  Even if it's just full of random values, seeing that will be easier to get to the form you want instead of starting from where you are now.

Comment: @ALollz, I have added some additional information. Also, I created my dictionary from 2 lists, one of managers and one of tickers, so I also have that data structure. When I use .DataFrame(index=[dictionary.keys, dictionary.values]) I get a 2 row df, where row 1 is all the managers and row 2 is all the tickers. How can I use the dictionary's key/value relationship to determine the length of the managers index, and add to each manager its respective tickers as the second level index? Please let me know if I should clarify further. Thank you

Comment: @user1717828 I have updated my question, does that clarify my problem? Please note that I have created a dictionary from two lists so that is available too. I would like to use my  dictionary to create the following DataFrame: Manager1 has 10 tickers, therefore the first level of my multi index is manager1's name, and the second level of the index is 10 rows, each named after the ticker. Columns contain values associated with each ticker. Hope this clarifies. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is in a good form to get into a dataframe with the right indices.

```
import pandas as pd
  
managers_tickers = {
    "AKO Capital": {
        "LIN": 0.25,
        "BKNG": 0.11,
        "EBAY": 0.13,
        "OTIS": 0.05,
        "PG": 0.035,
    },
    "Ackman Trust": {
        "BRK.B": 0.05,
        "WM": 0.15,
        "CAT": 0.12,
        "UPS": 0.05,
        "SDGR": 0.07,
    },
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(managers_tickers, orient="index").stack()

print(df)
```

The above prints:

```
AKO Capital   LIN      0.250
              BKNG     0.110
              EBAY     0.130
              OTIS     0.050
              PG       0.035
Ackman Trust  BRK.B    0.050
              WM       0.150
              CAT      0.120
              UPS      0.050
              SDGR     0.070
dtype: float64
```

You can get a single entry with:

```
df["Ackman Trust"]["WM"]
# prints 0.15
```

Comment: Thank you. Figured out my other question too- Appreciate it.